# using Adobe fonts with Flutter project

Tags: flutter, fonts, adobe

I am working in a Flutter project and I want to use the following Adobe fonts, how can I do that?
https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/myriad
https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/myriad-arabic

Answer (score 0):

You need to download this fonts and place it to `assets/fonts` folder at the root of your project. Next, add fonts to your `pubspec.yaml` file. For example:

```yaml
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: FontFamily
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/FontFamily-Regular.ttf
          style: regular
```

You can find more information in [Official Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts).

Comment: How can I download the Adobe font! this is the font that I want https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/myriad